async for loop with try catch exception
I have some code, to fetch prices from several markets:
def getprices(exchange):
    inst = getattr(ccxt, exchange)()
    prices = inst.fetch_ticker('symbol')
    data = {f'{exchange}': prices}
    return data

prices_data = {}
fails = []


for exchange in exchanges:
    try:
        prices_data.update(getprices(exchange))
        print('prices successfully pulled for ' +exchange)
    except:
        fails.append(exchange)
        print('price pull fail for ' +exchange)

This code is working, but problem i gathering is time of synchronous iteration is much slower than async i want to make it async.
I tried to make it async by several ways the only workable this one:
async def getprices(exchange):
    inst = getattr(ccxt, exchange)()
    prices = inst.fetch_ticker(symbol)
    data = {f'{exchange}': prices}
    return data

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(getprices(stock1))   
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(getprices(stock2))
    task3 = asyncio.create_task(getprices(stock3))
    task4 = asyncio.create_task(getprices(stock4))
    task5 = asyncio.create_task(getprices(stock5))
    task6 = asyncio.create_task(getprices(stock6))

    await task1
    await task2
    await task3
    await task4
    await task5
    await task6

asyncio.run(main())

This code is working, but how you see it has much more writed not necessary (i believe) blocks of code, and has no exception catch

how to make first code async

if you would keep data stock1, stock2 as list then you would use for-loop - and code would be shorter. And the same with task1, task2 ,...  - if you would keep it as list then you could use for-loop to make code shorter.

maybe you should use try/except inside getprices

You need to replace inst.fetch_ticker('symbol') by something asynchronous and then call it with await.
